# EXCEL WEB APP How to get Average of rows, grouped by a different column BUT not using the desktop program

Tags: excel

I'm learning excel, but is a course on the paid version installed on the PC, i'm working around that using excel from microsft web directly. the instruction is to use the Subtotal feature under Data tab, to get the average of Price per Country, but web version only has group by (and de-group). but here i even try to click on it, on Group Rows (maybe is group columns idk) and nothing happens.
The data look like this:
[Data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jC5Y.png)
The instruction from the course goes like this:
.
. . . .
-In the Data menu, click on the Subtotal option so that a configuration window appears. .
-Select the column CustomerCountry in the At each change in: dropdown menu. .
-Select Average as the aggregation method in the Use function: dropdown menu. .
-Ensure only OrderToDelivery is checked in the list of columns in the Add subtotal to: section. .
-If not already ticked, tick the Summary below data option.
. . . . . .
. Is there an optional argument on fx=Average that partition by the third column

Answer (score 0):

Excel on-line doesn't offer the (rather antiquated) Data, Subtotal feature. But you can create a pivot table (much more powerful than Data Subtotal anyway!) from that data to generate a very similar result.

You should be able to get a 1 month free trial license for Office 365 which entitles you to install Excel desktop: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/try